# Merge attribute data using spatial query in QGIS

Tags: qgis, query, fields-attributes

I have two vector layers that I wish to correlate attributes - a shapefile containing boundary polygons and a shapefile containing point locations.

I'm using the `vector>spatial query tool` to generate a new layer consisting of only boundaries that contain the specified points.

This works as I expect but I am looking for a solution that will provide me with an attribute table of point names with a corresponding column listing the boundary regions they fall within.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Join Attribute by Location](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php) tool.  This will add attribute columns of the polygon layer to your point layer.

Comment: Thanks artwork21 - this worked exactly as I need. The spatial query tool would benefit from an option to Join attributes.